How to set aggregationType to Multiple Files in boto3 for AWS AppFlow?
I am using boto3 to configure an AWS AppFlow. When setting up the destinationFlowConfigList, I need to set the aggregationType parameter. In the AWS console, I can see three options for aggregationType: None, Single File, and Multiple Files.
However, when I check the boto3 documentation, it only lists None and Single File as valid values for aggregationType.
Here's the snippet of my boto3 code:
destinationFlowConfigList=[
            {
                "connectorType": "S3",
                "destinationConnectorProperties": {
                    "S3": {
                        "bucketName": s3_bucket,
                        "s3OutputFormatConfig": {
                            "fileType": "CSV",
                            "prefixConfig": {
                                'prefixType': 'FILENAME',
                                'pathPrefixHierarchy': [
                                    'EXECUTION_ID'
                                ]
                            },
                            "aggregationConfig": {
                                "aggregationType": "None"
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

Here's the boto3 documentation extract:
destinationFlowConfigList=[
        {
            'connectorType': 'Salesforce'|'Singular'|'Slack'|'Redshift'|'S3'|'Marketo'|'Googleanalytics'|'Zendesk'|'Servicenow'|'Datadog'|'Trendmicro'|'Snowflake'|'Dynatrace'|'Infornexus'|'Amplitude'|'Veeva'|'EventBridge'|'LookoutMetrics'|'Upsolver'|'Honeycode'|'CustomerProfiles'|'SAPOData'|'CustomConnector'|'Pardot',
            'apiVersion': 'string',
            'connectorProfileName': 'string',
            'destinationConnectorProperties': {
                'Redshift': {
                    'object': 'string',
                    'intermediateBucketName': 'string',
                    'bucketPrefix': 'string',
                    'errorHandlingConfig': {
                        'failOnFirstDestinationError': True|False,
                        'bucketPrefix': 'string',
                        'bucketName': 'string'
                    }
                },
                'S3': {
                    'bucketName': 'string',
                    'bucketPrefix': 'string',
                    's3OutputFormatConfig': {
                        'fileType': 'CSV'|'JSON'|'PARQUET',
                        'prefixConfig': {
                            'prefixType': 'FILENAME'|'PATH'|'PATH_AND_FILENAME',
                            'prefixFormat': 'YEAR'|'MONTH'|'DAY'|'HOUR'|'MINUTE',
                            'pathPrefixHierarchy': [
                                'EXECUTION_ID'|'SCHEMA_VERSION',
                            ]
                        },
                        'aggregationConfig': {
                            'aggregationType': 'None'|'SingleFile',
                            'targetFileSize': 123
                        },
                        'preserveSourceDataTyping': True|False
                    }
                }

And also what I can see in AWS documentation:
AWS documentation
How can I configure aggregationType to use Multiple Files  in boto3 for AWS AppFlow? Is there an update or workaround to achieve this?
When I try to set aggregationType to Multiple Files, I get an error indicating that it's not a valid value.
The only way I found to achieve this is to change directly in the AWS console but a rather do that as code.
